# How to join 3 objects using c# *Lambda* and return t1.* and selected cols in t2 and t3

Tags: c#, lambda

*C# Lambda only please. No Linq - **Query style**.*

Looking for a strategy on how to join 3 objects that will output as following SQL (end goal of the c# lambda):

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.name pet_name, t3.name teacher_name
FROM user_profile t1
    INNER JOIN pet_profile t2 on t1.pet_id = t2.pet_id
    INNER JOIN pet_teacher t3 on t1.pet_teacher_id = t3.pet_teacher_id
```

**user_profile** columns:

1. user_id
2. user_fullname
3. pet_id
4. pet_teacher_id

**pet_profile** columns:

1. pet_id
2. name

**pet_teacher** columns:

1. pet_teacher_id
2. name

### What I have now is joining 2 objects with this query:

```
IQueryable<UserProfile> query = dataContext.UserProfile;

var queryTest = query
    .Join(dataContext.PetProfile,
        UserProfile => UserProfile.pet_id,
        t2 => t2.pet_id,
        (UserProfile, t2) => new { UserProfile, PetName = t2.name });
```

This will generate this SQL:

```
SELECT UserProfile.user_id,
    UserProfile.user_fullname,
    UserProfile.pet_id,
    UserProfile.pet_teacher_id,
    t2.name PetName
FROM user_profile UserProfile
    INNER JOIN pet_profile t2 on UserProfile.pet_id = t2.pet_id
```

[Q1: ] How can I join the 3rd table **pet_teacher**

[Q2: ] How to have all the fields of the user_profile without doing this manually:

```
var UserAndPet = query.Select(o => 
        new { o.UserProfile.user_id, 
            o.UserProfile.user_fullname,
            o.UserProfile.pet_id, 
            o.UserProfile.pet_teacher_id, 
            o.UserProfile.PetName, 
            o.UserProfile.TeacherName  }
    ).ToList();
enter code here
```

Comment: What's the opposition to query syntax?  Joins are much cleaner in query syntax than method syntax. Both are technically LINQ, for what it's worth.

Comment: I'm not good at remembering terminologies. I call that lambda as it is a lambda expression like. I got nothing against the query style.
I'll update my orig post to with 'non-query style' Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 3rd table

```
var queryTest = query
    .Join(dataContext.PetProfile,
        UserProfile => UserProfile.pet_id,
        t2 => t2.pet_id,
        (UserProfile, t2) => new { UserProfile, PetName = t2.name })
    .Join(datacontext.PetTeacher,
          x=>x.UserProfile.pet_teacher_id,
          y=>y.pet_teacher_id,(x,y)=>new {x.UserProfile,x.petname,x.teacherName})
```

For 2nd question, you can do this if all columns are from same table

```
var UserAndPet = query.Select(o =>o).ToList();
```

Comment: That solves the Q1! Thanks!
How about Q2? That code will show me this:

   " queryTest.Where(o => o.UserProfile.UserFullName == .... "

I am looking for something like this:

  " queryTest.Where(o => o.UserFullName == ... "

Comment: it has 3 joins different tables. Is it possible to have the SQL like (see the end goal SQL script) in Lambda?

Comment: @codeffreak: to achieve the structure you are looking for, you either need to have class that matches your expected structure or create anonymous object and select each property

Comment: I will accept this answer for solving Q1. I will just look around about Q2. Pretty sure there should be a way without creating a class and doing a select each property.